# Possibility of Taking Input from Keyboard or Dropdown menu

Tags: input, dropdown

This is the chunk of my code

```
<div class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon"> 
        <input type="text" id = "fromuser"></input>

    <select id="combobox">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <option value="abc">abc</option>
        <option value="cde">cde</option>
        <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
      </select>
      </span>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the User can either Type the value or select from the dropdown list. The challenge here is that the Input from Keyboard will be different from that given in dropdown. For example, the dropdown has three character string options but the user can type a  number such as 10, 20, 30 etc.

Is this type of input allowed possible? If so, can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Closest I could come to my problem is by dropping the select and use autocomplete . The full test code is as follows:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "abc",
      "def",
      "xyz"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );

function myFunction(){
    var NameValue = document.forms["FormName"]["tags"].value;
    window.alert(NameValue);
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="FormName" method="post" />
    <div class="ui-widget" >
      <input name= "tags" id="tags" type="text" onchange="myFunction()"/>
      <button name="btn-signup" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I know this is the final solution but maybe a way ahead.